# AWS Config query to track changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

I am implementing AWS Config and trying to figure out how to run a query which will tell us if there are any changes to the security groups or firewalls. I've setup a SNS topic and played with some existing rules such as ec2-security-group-attached-to-eni but I didn't find preexisting rules to alert the team if there were any changes in a security group. I did not find much online, would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old so I assume you found a solution?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/securityhub-cis-controls.html#cis-3.10-remediation

Security Hub has a solution for this, and you do not need to actually use Security Hub to setup the Alarm. So this is using CloudTrail and a CloudWatch metric and alarm and then SNS.